# Why does fn.call() fail after being assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Let's say we create a simple function

```
> function foo() { return 0; }
```

We could either call it directly

```
> foo();
> 0
```

Or we could call it using the Function.prototype.call() method

```
> foo.call({}); // Using empty object as this arg
> 0
```

So far so good. Now here is where things get strange. We can always assign a function to a variable in javascript, and call it under a new name

```
> var x = foo;
> x();
> 0
```

However, if we try the same thing with Function.prototype.call() we get an error

```
> var x = foo.call;
> x({});
> Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function
```

I imagine it has something to do with how the prototype chain works in javascript. Could someone explain to me the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you grab the reference to the `call` function:

```
var x = foo.call;
```

It does not carry over the `context`. In order to get this to work, you need to `bind` the context to `call`:

```
function foo() { return 0; }

var x = foo.call.bind(foo);

x(); //0
```

This can also be accomplished by binding after the creation of `x`:

```
function foo() { return 0; }

var x = foo.call;

x.bind(foo)(); //0
```

Comment: Thanks! Well explained answer.

Comment: This article seems to extend on what you said quite nicely also http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: You're welcome! And nice article find, it's a great supporting reference.